# Eclipse Plugin: How to show a menu contribution only when a persective is active?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I created a menu contribution for an Eclipse plugin.

I would like the menu only to be visible when the plugin perspective is active.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what I found, in an open source project, and it works for me:

```
<extension
      point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
   <menuContribution
         locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=additions">
      <menu
            id="menu1"
            label="Menu 1">
         <visibleWhen checkEnabled="false">
            <with variable="activeWorkbenchWindow.activePerspective">
                <equals value="myperspective"/>
            </with>
         </visibleWhen>
         <dynamic class="MenuPopulationClass"
                id="MenuPopulation"/>
      </menu>
   </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

Comment: Is it possible to use this approach if I want a menu visible when a specific view or page is active? for instance, show only when the Outline view is active at the moment.

Comment: Nevermind, you can use: variable="visiblePartId" and the outline view ID value.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the Command Framework.

[this tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseCommands/article.html) can help you

To restrict the visibility of your commands you should check par. 5

Answer (score 0):

This is a bare outline of what you need to do.

To limit the visibility of the top level menu, create an empty `ActionSet` through the Extension Point Selection dialog.

Next, add a `visibleWhen` expression to the top level menu item defined in the `plugin.xml`.  Right click on the menu item and select New -> visibleWhen.  Right click on the `visibleWhen` element and select New -> with

Set variable - "activeContexts"

Right click on the with element and select New -> iterate.  Select the new `iterate` element and modify its properties so that any matching element will cause the expression to evaluate `true`.

Right click on the `iterate` element and select New -> equals, then modify the value property.

value = your new ActionSet

Finally, add the top level menu item to your ActionSet.

Comment: I don't use actionSet but menu contributions using "menus" extension point. I found a way, cf my answer. Thank you anyway.